# Rsync-Daemon Max Connections Error

Tags: bash, rsync

I prefer to use rsync daemon for all of my rync needs because it provides clean centralized management and saves on system resources.  Accordingly, my `/etc/rsyncd.conf` contains multiple module entries.

My wrapper scripts for my actual rsync commands are all `while` loops that will instantly / repeatedly re-connect to corresponding rsync-daemons in case of dropped connections.

**Problem:**
The `max connections = 1` variable entry for each module is being read *globally* rather than *individually* per each module.  Thereby causing  `@ERROR: max connections (1) reached -- try again later` to take place (whichever rsync-daemon connects first gets the single available incorrectly *global* `max connection = 1`, causing all other connections to fail.. annoying ).

Without the `max connections = 1`, the `while` loop has the ability to spin up unlimited threads and consume unnecessary resources, hence a connections per module limit. Meanwhile the `max connections = 1` has the accompanying `per module` file.lock per documentation.

This is my `/etc/rsyncd.conf`:

```
[home]
path = /home/username
list = yes
use chroot = false
strict modes = false
uid = root
gid = root
read only = yes
# Data source information
max connections = 1
lock file = /var/run/rsyncd-home.lock

[prod-bkup]
path = /media/username/external/Server-Backups/Prod/today
list = yes
use chroot = false
strict modes = false
uid = root
gid = root
# Don't allow to modify the source files
read only = yes
max connections = 1
lock file = /var/run/rsyncd-prod-bkup.lock

[test-bkup]
path = /media/username/external/Server-Backups/Test/today
list = yes
use chroot = false
strict modes = false
uid = root
gid = root
# Don't allow to modify the source files
read only = yes
max connections = 1
lock file = /var/run/rsyncd-test-bkup.lock

[VminRoot2]
path = /root/VDI-Files
list = yes
use chroot = false
strict modes = false
uid = root
gid = root
# Don't allow to modify the source files
read only = yes
max connections = 1
lock file = /var/run/rsyncd-VminRoot2.lock
```

This is an example of one of my rsync-daemon wrapper scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
while [ 1 ]
do

   cputool --load-limit 7.5 -- nice -n -15 rsync -avxP --no-i-r --rsync-path="rsync" --log-file=/var/log/rsync-home.log --exclude 'snap'  --exclude 'lost+found' --exclude=".*" --exclude=".*/" 127.0.0.1::home /media/username/external/home-files-only && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
   
    if [ "$?" = "0" ] ; then
        echo "rsync completed normally"
        exit
    else
        echo "Rsync failure. Backing off and retrying..."
        sleep 10
    fi
done

#end of shell script
```

**Question**
How can I get rid of the `ERROR: max connections (1) reached -- try again later` error?